# Background upload in PHP

Tags: php, upload, background

I am working with a form that allows me to upload files via a local folder and FTP.
So I want to move files over ftp (which already works)

Because of performance reasons I chose this process to run in the background so I use nfcftpput (linux)

In CLI the following command works perfectly:
ncftpput-b-u name -p password -P 1980 127.0.0.1 /upload/ /home/Downloads/upload.zip

(Knowing that the b-parameter triggers background process)
But if I run it via PHP it does not work (without the-b parameter it does)

PHP code:

```
$cmd = "ncftpput -b -u name -p password -P 1980 127.0.0.1 /upload/ /home/Downloads/upload.zip";
$return = exec($cmd);
```

Comment: you have the script in a php webpage and you want to start a background process? - never going to happen! or directly php script in server like: /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/script.php - crontab like ?

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following:

1) Use the command $cmd = "ncftpput -b -u name -p password -P 1980 127.0.0.1 /upload/ /home/Downloads/upload.zip &";
(Notice the &)

2) Try php's proc_open function http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Answer (score 0):

Try adding '&' at the end of command, this will fork it on linux level. Also try shell_exec(), if previous won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [pcntl_fork](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php). This [user note](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php#94338) has information how to correctly spawn a background process. Note that the extension that provides this function might not be activated in your PHP installation.

Answer (score 0):

The best working solution for me is the following code:

```
function executeBackgroundProces($command) {

    $command = $command . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!';
    exec ( $command, $op );
    $pid = ( int ) $op [0];
    if ($pid != "")
        return $pid;

    return false;
}
```

The command I run is: "ls bashfile"
The bash file contains commands like the upload and deletion of the original files separated by ;
This works fine by me